# 2 pixels difference between divs

Tags: html, css

if you look at http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/w4HWn/1/ you will see that the DIV on the right side "Interacting with the nature" is 1 or 2px lower than the DIVs on the left side. Where does this difference come from? Thanks

Comment: Yeap, next time => `Right Click => Inspect element` with Chrome, or Firebug under Firefox, or nothing under IE.

Comment: The margin-top 4px was to put more space between the lines of text. But you're right, without this the DIVs are aligned. How could I increase the space between paragraphs without affecting the DIVs alignment? Tks

Comment: So you want `line-height`, not `margin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#source-region, #source-oursource p {
margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Remove that, and there's no difference:
http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/w4HWn/1/

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, then it comes from your css `#source-region, #source-oursource p{margin-top:4px;}`
[here is the link on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4HWn/4/)